# How to add new features to existing licensing functionality which won't affect existing clients?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an application where I am enabling/disabling features through license key.  Some features are enabled by default. All of my current clients have access to all features to my application. Now I want to divide my application in Silver, Gold and Platinum Edition. Over here I want to include by default features as well in my license key.  The challenging part is, I do not want to send new license key to my old clients and also want them to access the features. This restriction would be applicable to new clients only.

The whole idea behind this is include all the features in license key and based on the edition, let the user use the functionality. Earlier I was giving some features as a free which I want to stop for new clients.

For an example(please see the link for more detail),

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjyhN.jpg

Code:

Currently I am using following code:

```
if (licKeyDO.Features.ContainsKey("Feature A"))
    FeatureA.IsEnabled = true;
else
    FeatureA.IsEnabled = false;
```

My issue is if I am making the key with Silver Edition privileges and sending out the new build than my older client will only have two features which I want to avoid.  How can I handle this situation?

Please let me know if I am unable to explain it clearly before directly giving negative remarks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify somehow your older clinets.
If your logic will be something like:

```
if (licKeyDO == null)
{
    //enable all features
}
```

... then you'll be risking in let **new clients** without license the all privileges - which you don't wan't to do.